# PHP preg_match get the last item

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a PHP string with a list of items, and I would like to get the last one.

The reality is much more complex, but it boils down to:

```
$Line = 'First|Second|Third';
if ( preg_match( '@^.*|(?P<last>.+)$@', $Line, $Matches ) > 0 )
{
    print_r($Matches);
}
```

I expect `Matches['last']` to contain 'Third', but it does not work. Rather, I get Matches[0] to contain the full string and nothing else.
What am I doing wrong?

Please no workarounds, I can do it myself but I would really like to have this working with preg_match

Comment: can you please explain why it has to be regex? if the delimiter is  just the pipe, then `end(explode('|', $line)` would really be much easier. Or maybe substr with strrpos.

Comment: If you just want the last portion you can do `substr(strrchr($Line, '|'), 1);` Not sure the reasoning behind needing to use a regex. Can you possibly elaborate a little on why?

Comment: It has to be regexp because the actual string is much more complex than my example. You are right, I would never use a regexp on such a simple string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have this:

```
'@^.*|(?P<last>.+)$@'
     ^
```

... but I guess you are looking for a *literal* `|`:

```
'@^.*\|(?P<last>.+)$@'
     ^^
```

Answer (score 2):

If your syntax is always kinda the same, and by that I mean that uses the `|` as separator, you could do the following, if you like it.

```
$Line = 'First|Second|Third' ;
$line_array = explode('|', $Line);
$line_count = count($line_array) - 1;

echo $line_array[$line_count];
```

or

```
$Line = 'First|Second|Third' ;
$line_array = explode('|', $Line);
end($line_array);

echo $line_array[key($line_array)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use :

```
 $Line = 'First|Second|Third' ;
   $lastword = explode('|', $line);
    echo $lastword['2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example of PHP preg_match to get the last match:**

```
<?php
  $mystring = "stuff://sometext/2010-01-01/foobar/2016-12-12.csv";
  preg_match_all('/\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/', $mystring, $matches);
  print_r($matches);
  print("\nlast match: \n");
  print_r($matches[0][count($matches[0])-1]);
  print("\n");
?>
```

**Prints the whole object returned and the last match:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2010-01-01
            [1] => 2016-12-12
        )

)

last match: 
2016-12-12
```